# Ubuntu bypassing the login screen after reboot

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, auto-login

I have been using ubuntu 16.04 for last two weeks now. when i login to ubuntu it goes directly to desktop bypassing the login screen and  after a 5-10 sec freeze/delay goes to login screen and ask for password to proceed as should have happened in the first go. I tried restarting the lightdm going to hard terminal but the tty7 screen still doesnt respond.
This is the content of /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file

```
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=ravish
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Haven't find any solutions yet.
Any help will be much appreciated!

There is no Xorg.log but I found these errors in apport.log

```
ERROR: apport (pid 4084) Thu Aug 18 18:41:30 2016: called for pid 2813, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615
ERROR: apport (pid 4084) Thu Aug 18 18:41:30 2016: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
ERROR: apport (pid 4084) Thu Aug 18 18:41:30 2016: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch")
ERROR: apport (pid 4084) Thu Aug 18 18:41:30 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 4084) Thu Aug 18 18:41:35 2016: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 4942) Thu Aug 18 18:47:19 2016: called for pid 4157, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615
ERROR: apport (pid 4942) Thu Aug 18 18:47:19 2016: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
ERROR: apport (pid 4942) Thu Aug 18 18:47:19 2016: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch")
ERROR: apport (pid 4942) Thu Aug 18 18:47:19 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 4942) Thu Aug 18 18:47:19 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 3763) Thu Aug 18 18:53:02 2016: called for pid 2795, signal 6, core limit 18446744073709551615
ERROR: apport (pid 3763) Thu Aug 18 18:53:02 2016: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
ERROR: apport (pid 3763) Thu Aug 18 18:53:02 2016: executable: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (command line "/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch")
ERROR: apport (pid 3763) Thu Aug 18 18:53:02 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 3763) Thu Aug 18 18:53:02 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

Comment: just to clarify your wants and needs:
* you want to be forced to log in after the computer started?

Comment: yeah.. and anyway if it is bypassing as well.. it shouldnt go back to login screen

Answer (score 0):

remove those lines starting with "autologin" from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
This should resolve your first problem: it won't log you in automatically anymore.

Just for reference - my lightdm.conf in 16.04 looks like this:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login = true
greeter-hide-users = false
allow-guest = false
```

In the next step have a look at various logfiles for clues on why you are logged out again:

- `/var/log/lightdm/*.log`
- `/var/log/Xorg.?.log`